# I want to know what the different between is two way create child process in Linux with fork()?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

I want to create 2 child process and 1 parent process with fork()

The first method:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
int main(void){
    pid_t b,c;
        printf("a");

    if(0 == ( b = fork())){
            printf("b");
    }
    if(0 == ( c = fork())){
            printf("c");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The second method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main(int argv,char ** argc){
  pid_t fpid1,fpid2;
    fpid1 = fork();
    if(fpid1 == 0){
        printf("b");
    }else{
        fpid2 = fork();
        if( fpid2 == 0){
            printf("c");

        }else{
            printf("a");

        }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

After run these code,i found the answer is different
The first is

```
a
b
c
```

The second is 
random

i forgot add fpid2 = fork(); sorry!!
please help me

Comment: Dare to show one of those "random" outputs?

Comment: The output you show for the 1st snippet is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first program `fork`s twice, but the second one - only once, so that `fpid_2` is left unititialized, hence the undefined behavior (the *randomness* you're talking about).

Comment: oops,i forgot to add fork for it

Comment: so, if add fork for fpid_2 what the different between these code

Comment: @ShawnLiu, the `if`s are nested in the second piece of code, while in the first one they're not, for example

Answer (score 0):

Besides the main process the 1st snippet creates three processes, the 2nd only two.

(Assuming `stdout` is line buffered)

The first snippet prints in the following, probably mixed up:

```
a
ab
ac
abc
```

The 2nd outputs, probably mixed up as well:

```
b
c
a
```